# solidity - I want to call the transfer function from my ERC20 token contract through delegatecall

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I would like to use delegatecall to send many people who participated in airdrop my token with one transaction so I'm trying to call the transfer() function declared in ERC20 token contract that I deployed in MultiSend contract. First code is Multisend Contract

```
 contract MultiSend {                                                
  function multiSend(address _token, address[] addresses, uint256 amount) public {

for(uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  require(_token.delegatecall(bytes32(keccak256("transfer(address, uint256)")), addresses[i], amount));
}
```

}
}

Below code is transfer() in my ERC20 token contract.

```
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
public
returns (bool) {
    unlockBalance(msg.sender);

    locker storage l = lockerList[msg.sender];

    if (l.isLocker) {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender].available);
        require(_to != address(0));

        balances[msg.sender].available = balances[msg.sender].available.sub(_value);
        addLockedUpTokens(_to, _value, l.lockUpPeriod, l.unlockCount);
    } else { 
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender].available);
        require(_to != address(0));

        balances[msg.sender].available = balances[msg.sender].available.sub(_value);
        balances[_to].available = balances[_to].available.add(_value);
    }
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

    return true;
}
```

I deployed MultiSend contract successfully and ERC20 token contract also  works on its own. However, when I tried to send transaction  through MultiSend contract, this transaction failed. I don't know why I cannot send tokens through this contract.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I suspect you're misunderstanding what `delegatecall` does.

Comment: @smarx Actually, to send the token to the people who participated in the airdrop, I created a smart contact,MultiSend contract, that would send a token to many people in a single transaction. So the new MultiSend smart contact was deployed to send a token to people from the wallet where the token was stored for the airdrop. The MultiSend smart contact includes a multiSend function to call the transfer function declared in the ERC20 token contract.By the way, I don't know why a failure occurs if I make a transaction using the multiSend function.

Comment: I suggest you read about what `delegatecall` does. It essentially means "run the code of that other contract but with my storage."

Comment: To do what you're trying to do, either transfer tokens to `MultiSend` and have it make a regular call to `token.transfer(...)`, or call `token.approve(...)` to approve the `MultiSend` contract and then have `MultiSend` use `token.transferFrom(...)`.

Comment: Hey @Jeyoung check this out, already answered here. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48290/how-to-airdrop-tokens-successfully